# How focal length changes upon introducing a medium between lenses?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, lenses

[image]

The question is from a standard textbook H.C Verma and the solutions suggests that the answer shall be (c) increases, which contradicts with my solution.

[image]

Using the above formula on introduction of medium :

- since $\mu > 1$ then the 3rd term denominator increases
- thus the 3rd term decreases
- so $\frac{1}{f}$ increases
- thus $f$ decreases.

The above is my solution.

I would like to know where did i go wrong ?

**Edit 1:**
I later figured out that on introduction of an medium the negative value of 1/f decreases i/e, the negative value of f increases and being a concave lens the more the negative value of f the more the focal length, thus the focal length increases.Thanks for everyone else's contribution !

Comment: ya i do mean μ and that blue character refers d divided by μ

Comment: yes i had kept it in mind that f1f2 is positive but i didn't consider that the first two terms are negative and since the 3rd term decreases the negative value of 1/f decreases and eventually the negative value of f increases i.e, its focal length increases. I could figure it out now with the help of an example.

Answer (score 2):

The focal length of the combination of lenses is determined by how much a ray of light bends as it passes through the system. The more it bends, the shorter the focal length.

When the space between the two concave lenses is filled with a material with a refractive index $\mu$ which is greater than that of air but less than that of the glass used (ie $1<\mu<\mu_g$), the ray will bend in the same direction wrt the normal at each interface, but not as much as before, because the difference in refractive indices is less. So the lens combination will be weaker, with a longer focal length.

Comment: thanx ! i now noticed that it has more to do with the reasoning than with the formula !